# SSIS package does nothing when invoked by agent

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent

SSIS package loops through input files.  For each file, flatfile parse adds records to a DB table, then file is renames/moved for archiving.  After all files, package calls a sproc to delete all year-old records.

Package runs from visual studio OK.  Put in SSIS package store, run from there, no problem.

Create an SQL Agent job to run package.  Job does *something* for about five minutes, announces it was **successful**, but no new records in DB and no renaming of input files.

Package uses dedicated login for SQL Server privileges.  Job is run as HOSTNAME-SVC which has read/write privileges on the input directory and the archive directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you setup logging for the package?  You could add a script task to the For-Each Loop Container that runs a Dts.Events.FireInformation command during each loop.  This could help you track the file name it finds, the number of loops it does, how long each loop takes, etc.  You could also add a logging step at the end so that you know it is at least exiting the For-Each Loop container successfully.

If you find that the package is running successfully but not looping through any files at all, then you may want to test using a simpler package that reads one file only and loads it into a staging table.  If that works, then go the next step of looping over all the files in the director and only importing the one file over and over again.  If that works, then go the next step of changing the file connection to match the file that it finds in the For-Each Loop Container file enumerator task.

If the package isn't looping over any files and you can't get it to see even the one file you tested loading from the job, then try creating a proxy account with your credentials and running the job as the proxy account.  If that works, then you probably have a permissions issue with your service account.

If the package doesn't import anything even with the proxy account, then you may want to log into the server as the service account and try to run the SSIS package in BIDS.  If that works, then you may want to deploy it to the server and run the package from the server (which will really use your machine, but at least it uses the ssis definition from the server).  If this works, then try running the package from the agent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand.  The package has already been thoroughly tested under several Windows accounts, and it does find all the files and rename all the files.

Under the Agent, it does absolutely nothing visible, but takes five minutes to do it.  NO permissions errors or any other errors.  I didn't mention that an earlier attempt DID get permissions errors because we had failed to give the service acount access to the input and output directories.

I cannot log in as the service account to try that because I do not have a pasword for it.  But sa isd job owner so it should be able to switch to the service account--and the access errors we got ten days ago show that it can.  The package itself has not changed in those ten days.  We just deleted the job in order to do a complete "dress rehearsal" of deployment procedure.

So what has changed, I presume, is some detail in the deployment procedure, which unfortunately was not in source control at the time it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something different about the permissions.  We made the problem go away by allowing "everyone" to read the directory on the production server.  For some unknown reason, we did not have to do that on the test server.

When the job tried to fetch the file list, instead of getting an error (which would be logged) it got an empty list.  Why looping through an empty list took five minutes is still a mystery, as is the lack of permissions.  But at least what happened has been identified.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Was able to figure out what was happening by setting the logging option of the SQL Server Agent Job.

Edit the step in the job that runs the package, go to the logging tab and pick "SSIS log provider for SQL Server" and, in the configuration string, I picked (using the drop down) the OLEDB connector that was in the package, it happens to connect to SQL Server in question.

I was then able to view more details in the history of that job, and confirmed that it was not finding files.  By changing permissions on the directory to match the sql server agent account, the package finally executed properly.

Hope this helps.

You may want to turn logging off after you resolve your issue, depending on how often your package will run and how much information logging provides in your case.

Regards,
Bertin

Comment: We did a lot of examining of permissions, so that may not be it, but the elapsed time makes checking it now not feasible.